# Create a .app with python in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, .app

Hey I was just wondering if it is possible to create an executable file (mac) with python in eclipse classic? If not, than how can I create an executable with my python code? I cant use py2app because that dosen't work with Pygame.

Comment: FYI, I got py2app to work with pygame once. I remember finding a tutorial online that walked me through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.org).  It should be able to create an executable for Windows, Linux, and Mac.  It does have support for pygame (and I've used it successfully to build several programs using pygame, albeit only in Windows and Linux), but you might need to apply this [bugfix](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/406) first, depending on if the latest download has fixed this or not.

I believe it runs independently from Eclipse.

Comment: Specifically see this part in the docs: http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-mac-os-x-app-bundles